# The spring boot login process has this error: org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Bad credentials",

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to implement a login functionality, from the stored user credentials.

but it gives error as :

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Bad credentials",
```

note:

Password is stored encrypted in database.

Controller code:

```
 @PostMapping("/login")
public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> login(@RequestBody JwtRequest authenticationRequest) throws Exception {

    String encodedPassword = this.passwordEncoder.encode( authenticationRequest.getPassword());
    String userName =  authenticationRequest.getUsername();

 try {
     authenticationManager.authenticate(
             new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                     userName,
                     encodedPassword
             )
     );
 }catch(Exception e){
     throw new CustomErrorException(
             HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
             "the authentication process has errors : "+e.toString()
     );
 }




    final Employee emp = employeeService.findOne(authenticationRequest.getUsername());
    if(emp != null){
        System.out.println(" *** the employee  ******** "+emp.toString());
    }else{
        System.out.println(" *** the employee not found  ******** ");
    }
    final CustomeEmployee cEmp = customeEmployeeService.loadUserByUsername(authenticationRequest.getUsername());
    final String token = jwtTokenUtil.generateToken(cEmp);

    System.out.println("the request cam e along wy step 2");
    /**     --------------------------     */

    ArrayNode authorities = mapper.createArrayNode();
    for(GrantedAuthority authority : cEmp.getAuthorities()) {
        authorities.add(authority.getAuthority());
    }

    Map<String, Object> result = getConfiguration(emp, cEmp);

    result.put("token", token);

    return ResponseEntity.ok(result);


}
```

Appearantly the process is not passing throug the

```
    authenticationManager.authenticate(
             new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                     userName,
                     encodedPassword
             )
     );
```

It says the credential errors.

Note: Password and username is 100% correct.

Comment: Don't pass the encoded password, pass the plain password.

Comment: you miss-use spring-security! if you *really wanted that*, have a look at [`UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/main/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java) (and extended class), but what you try, can easily be achieved with [`spring.security.user.name|password|roles` properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.security.spring.security.user.name) (+default config)